# How to build ordered list from SQL query

Tags: jquery, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to build a where-user viewer viewing bills of material for an html page by grabbing sql data. I have the sql connection working, my html table builder working, and passing the user inputs to parameters working and a recursive sql query to get every parent. Unfortunately, the output grows with each parent and it is a little confusing. To fix that I would like to have each parent expand when clicked and condense down when clicked.

My searching has yielded that I should probably grab all data from the sql query, and somehow structure this into a format to make an ordered list. With an ordered list, you could leverage some jquery for user interact with.

I'm seeking advise for how to get dynamic sql results output to an ordered list? Using vb.net, aspx, sql server.

Minimum table output reads...

ChildID : ParentID

Comment: In the codebehind, load the data into a datatable, then loop through the rows and concatenate the <li> elements.  Then assign the concatenated HTML to an asp:Literal.

Comment: @TonyHinkle Thanks Tony. I am looking for something a little more complex.When I start looping through the rows, I can only make it go one level deep and am unsure how to nest the second level. This is where I need help.

Comment: You could set the query response to give you the html format for the list. For each parent, get the result set as a formated html content. Set the classes and the jQuery functionality upon it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the query to get a pre formated html code.
Something like this:

```
SELECT CAST('<li class="Collapseble"> <span class="IDParent">' + cast(compras.IDCompras as nvarchar(max)) 
+ '</ span>' as nvarchar(max) ) +  
(STUFF(
        (SELECT 
        CAST('\<div class="ResultSet"><span class="IDMaterial">IDMaterial: ' as nvarchar(max))  
            + cast([idmaterial] as nvarchar(max)) + cast('</span>' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        , CAST('<span class="Quantidade">Quantidade: ' + cast([quantidade] as nvarchar(max)) 
            + '</span> </div>' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
        FROM DetalheCompra 
        WHERE (IDCompras = compras.idcompras) 
        FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) + '</li>'
    AS Detalhes
```

FROM compras

The result set would be something like this:

```html
<li class="Collapseble"> <span class="IDParent">16</ span><div class="ResultSet"><span class="IDMaterial">IDMaterial: 29</span><span class="Quantidade">Quantidade: 150.00</span> </div></li>
<li class="Collapseble"> <span class="IDParent">17</ span><div class="ResultSet"><span class="IDMaterial">IDMaterial: 27</span><span class="Quantidade">Quantidade: 2.00</span> </div>\<div class="ResultSet"><span class="IDMaterial">IDMaterial: 29</span><span class="Quantidade">Quantidade: 1.00</span> </div></li>
<li class="Collapseble"> <span class="IDParent">1016</ span><div class="ResultSet"><span class="IDMaterial">IDMaterial: 27</span><span class="Quantidade">Quantidade: 20.00</span> </div></li>
```

Then you just have to implement the jQuery functionality to collapse or expand the `<li>` elements.

Is that about what you were looking for?